# Script for generating thousands of test products to Magento?

Tags: php, magento

As the title suggests, I'm wondering if there's a way to generate thousands of simple test products (for a local development store) via a PHP script. I have some custom extensions that load different product collections, and they work fine with the standard sample data, but I'd like to test them in a more "real world" setting. So for that I'd like to have a large number of products in the store (as in tens of thousands). They wouldn't need images, and names/SKUs etc could just be incremental values.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Sounds like you just need to make a loop that iterates some "tens of thousands" times and each iteration generates a random product?

Comment: Yep, actually found a Fontis blog post showing how to make products like that, so looped it up and it's working fine! I'll add the answer here once I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, here's how, courtesy of [this blog post](http://www.fontis.com.au/blog/magento/creating-magento-products-script) over at Fontis:

```
<?php
$i = 1;
$numberofprods = 100;
$numberofprods = range($i,$numberofprods);
foreach($numberofprods as $product) {
++$i; $name = "Product Number ".$i;
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->setSku($i);
$product->setName($name);
$product->setDescription("This widget will give you years of trouble-free widgeting.");
$product->setShortDescription("High-end widget.");
$product->setPrice(99.99);
$product->setTypeId('simple');
$product->setAttributeSetId(4); // need to look this up
$product->setCategoryIds("3,8"); // need to look these up
$product->setWeight(1.0);
$product->setTaxClassId(2); // taxable goods
$product->setVisibility(4); // catalog, search
$product->setStatus(1); // enabled
// assign product to the default website
$product->setWebsiteIds(array(Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getWebsite()->getId()));
$product->save(); 
}; ?>
```

It's best to do this in batches as it seems to be quite a processor heavy task, so I added the amount as a range - so for example you can have *$i = 1;$numberofprods = 1000;* and then when that's finished *$i = 1001;$numberofprods = 2000;* and so on.

To run it, I simply saved it as a template file in *app/design/frontend/default/template/createproducts.phtml* and then called that from a CMS page like *{{block type="core/template" template="createproducts.phtml"}}*. Then each time you load that page it'll run and create your products.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore, the products are not shown by default unless they are saved manually in the backend. My suspicion is that the qty also needs to be set (or inventory management needs to be disabled for each product).